# My AppleScript script wont work

Tags: applescript, xcode

I am a starter in AppleScript and there is an issue with my script I cant fix.

The script is:

```
display dialog "How long do you want the timer to go for in seconds?" default answer ""

set time to "text returned"

display dialog "Click start to start." buttons {"Start", "Cancel"}

if the answer is equal to "Start" then
    delay "time"
end if
repeat 10 times
    beep
end repeat
```

---

The error message is "error "Can’t set time to \"text returned\"." number -10006 from time" (I am making a timer)

Comment: You have lots of errors in that script! The first one your getting is because `time` is a _property_ of a `date object` and cannot be used in the manner you have.

Answer (score 1):

The following example AppleScript code is just to show changes made to your code to make it flow without the obvious errors that your code has. It does not include proper error handling as would be appropriate to handle all results of the logic flow. Keep learning!

```
display dialog "How long do you want the timer to go for in seconds?" default answer ""

set thisLong to text returned of result

display dialog "Click start to begin." buttons {"Cancel", "Start"} default button 2

if button returned of result is "Start" then
    delay thisLong
    repeat 10 times
        beep
    end repeat
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying, welcome to AppleScript! I know it can be frustrating at first but stick with it, it will be worth it in the end!

So, here is the script that I wrote that accomplishes what you are trying to achieve:

```
set secondCount to (text returned of (display dialog "How long do you want the timer to go for in seconds?" default answer "")) as integer
set startDialog to display dialog "Click start to start." buttons {"Start", "Cancel"} default button "Start"

if button returned of startDialog is "Start" then
    delay secondCount
end if

repeat 10 times
    beep
end repeat
```

One thing you will notice is that I actually assigned a variable to the "make dialog" lines, this will allow you to reference their output at any given point further down in the script. In the first line, I assign the variable "secondCount" to whatever text is returned from that dialog, formatted as an integer.

By setting the text returned from this dialog to an integer, you could wrap this in a repeat & try block to insist that the user enters a valid number before proceeding (but I digress)

There are some more things that I could go over with this one but I think I will leave it here for now. I hope it helps!